# Laravel 9 Install vue router for vue 2.6.12

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I try installing vue router with run command "npm install vue-router" but then showing error like this:

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR!   dev vue@"^2.6.12" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.2.0" from vue-router@4.0.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-router
npm ERR!   vue-router@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-20T12_19_15_072Z-debug-0.log

please help

Answer (score 9):

I solved it by installing `vue-router@3`.

```
npm install vue-router@3 --save
```

You can just try this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your **vue** is not the latest version, it gives this error.

Use previous versions of **vue-router**.

[To access old versions of vue-router, use the versions tab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router)

Example : npm i vue-router@3.5.3